# Windows Phone 7 - dynamically set button background color from Hex?

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change custom color for Rectangle.Fill or Grid.Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532056/change-custom-color-for-rectangle-fill-or-grid-background)

I'm trying to dynamically set a button background color from Hex in Windows Phone 7.

```
    SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
    myBrush.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#123456");
    pbMood.Background = myBrush;
```

ColorTranslator seems to not be available.  That line gives a compiler error that it isn't found.

Am I looking in the wrong place (a different namespace?), or is there another way to do this from code?

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  I will need this information shortly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This class is not available in Silverlight.

[Instead, you can write it yourself](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2009/04/22/silverlight-get-color-from-hex.aspx).

```
public static SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
{
    return new SolidColorBrush(
        Color.FromArgb(
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(7, 2), 16)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: You must use

Color.FromArgb(
              Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(0, 2), 16),
              Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(2, 2), 16),
              Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(4, 2), 16),
              Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(6, 2), 16)

Comment: @jcrada: Only if the string doesn't start with `#`.

Comment: @SLaks:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occure when this method call

Comment: @MansinhDodiya: As the error is trying to tell you, your parameters are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532056/change-custom-color-for-rectangle-fill-or-grid-background) gives an even simpler way to use hex values to create a SolidColorBrush.

```
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { R = 0xFF, G = 0xA6, B = 0x10});
```

Comment: This is the [Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) syntax. It's available on Windows Phone, and I use it myself. Also, the Windows Phone classes at play here are System.Windows.Media.Color and System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush. Windows Phone doesn't use [System.Drawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021262/cannot-find-system-drawing-dll-in-reference) which is for GDI+ on desktop Windows.

Comment: I mistakenly thought that the OP was asking about `System.Drawing.Color`, which is immutable.

Comment: scrl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() {A=Convert.ToByte( 255*.7), R = 0X32, G = 0x40, B = 0x65 });

works with windows phone 8