# Coloring a Polygon

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, colors, polygon

I want to Color a Polygon...

This is the Polygon in my Compass.xaml:

```
<Polygon x:Name="arrow"  Points="5, 90 35, 90 35, 160 65, 160 65, 90 95, 90 50, 5" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="White" Margin="42,32,184,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="163" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Polygon.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateArrow" Angle="0"  CenterX="50" CenterY="160" />
    </Polygon.RenderTransform>
</Polygon>
```

And this is where I get the Color from:

```
Channel lbi = (Channel) GlobalVariables.ChannelList[Channelindex];

lbi.Color => "0xED1C24"
```

Now i have to fill this Polygon with this Color...

I tried to do it with

```
arrow.fill('blue');
```

(Just random color to try out if it would work.) but it didn't work...

Can somebody help me out?

EDIT:

Ok it works now.

```
string[] colorsplit = currentChannel.Color.Split('x');
arrow.Fill = GetColorFromHexa("#FF"+colorsplit[1]);
```

the Problem was that I didn't knew that i have to put #FF in front of the string..

Comment: Based on the following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305968/windows-phone-7-dynamically-set-button-background-color-from-hex : You could use arrow.Fill = GetColorFromHexa("#FFED1C24");

Comment: I am not sure if the Color i get is Hexa Color... this doesn't really work..

Comment: If you aren't sure that you are getting a Color, then why are you trying to fill the polygon with it?

Comment: You understand me wrong :) i wasn't sure if it the format is hexa. but looks like it is :) i willl try paul's answer. not sure if it's you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C#?

```
arrow.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
```

Comment: this works but like i said, i need to do it with the color information: "0x945316"

Comment: arrow.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0x94,0x53,0x16));

Comment: when i do this it just turns black.. doesn't matter what kind of values i take...

Comment: Alpha must be 255, otherwise it will be transparent

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
arrow.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

?