# Cannot find System.Drawing.dll in reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I'm having a weird problem. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone and want to refer System.Drawing.dll. I right-clicked "reference" in the project and clicked "Add reference...", however, I cannot find System.Drawing.dll under .NET tab. Any ideas why? Thanks!

Fei

Comment: That's a Winforms assembly, it requires the host OS to support GDI+.  Not available on a phone.  Not actually something you should worry about much, GDI+ is, erm, special.

Answer (score 5):

That's a Winforms assembly, it requires the host OS to support GDI+, which is not available for wp7.

Have a look at [System.Windows.Media](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.aspx) instead