# System.Drawing does not exist

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing on Windows Phone 7.1 and can not find System.Drawing, for example in this code

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap sfondo_panorama 
{
    get 
    {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("sfondo_panorama", resourceCulture);
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that System.Drawing exist in WP7 runtime.

Comment: I don't think it exists either. You'd probably have to use [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) EDIT: Or depending on the usage, [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: do you use some plugins which insert these automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think System.Drawing available in WP7 and I'm not really sure what you are trying to do but try `System.Windows.Media` and `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`.

Comment: Yes, I was reading this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021262/cannot-find-system-drawing-dll-in-reference), but it is not possible because this code is automatically inserted when you add a new image in Resources files.

Comment: @Spode Resources (resx) files are simply XML data files. You can workaround this: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2009/07/14/silverlight-quick-tip-resx-image-resources.aspx