# Change custom color for Rectangle.Fill or Grid.Background

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

i can change custom color Rectangle with something like : "#A125AA" in xaml.

But i don't know where to find code change custom color i have

i just know code for color arealy have

```
this.gridgcolor.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set the color through RGB. This isn't done in hex like you're doing in your xaml.

```
Color color = new Color() { R = 255, G = 255, B = 255 };
Brush brush= new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

the hex values you have in your example #A125AA are also RGB
R = A1,
G = 25,
B = AA

You could convert these values with a [helper method](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/tag/convert-hex-string-to-color/) so you can add them to your Color object.

If you want to use the names, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is also a list of a lot of RGB codes matched to their names

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hexadecimal number directly in your XAML, as the following shows :-

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0"
          Background="#A125AA"></Grid>
```